# Correct padding not present in IE/Safari

Tags: css

I have padding: 0 40px 0 40px on the main element of each page.

In chrome, the layout looks correct with the correct padding.  Here the image shows the correct padding using the developer tools.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbJJs.png

However in IE and safari, the padding is not present and the text/image are shifted to the outer body element.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbJJs.png#1

I cant figure out why this is happening. The IE developer tools don't help me much either

Same padding issues for the home page and category pages.
www.luminoto.com

Thanks

Comment: Hey, could you perhaps provide a link to a live version? Perhaps jsfiddle? Or give us some code or something! My thoughts are that it has to do with the `box-sizing`. On those elements giving you grief, try adding `box-sizing: border-box;`... IE is pooper.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not have `display:block` in its browser stylesheet for the `main` element, so you have to add it explicitly in your stylesheet – otherwise it’ll just be treated as an `inline` element (and all the content will just “flow out” of it).

You can add it directly to your formatting for `.photo_main` – although the better place to do this would be inside a “reset” stylesheet meant to equalize such browser differences.

Not sure if that’s the same issue Safari is facing, but give it a try and see if it fixes that as well.

Comment: thanks.  i actually got help on code mentor prior to seeing this and that was exactly the solution.  I used display: inline-block though.